# sequentially send stdout from subprocess.Popen via socket

Tags: python, sockets, subprocess, popen

I know this has been anwered many times before, but I haven't find a working way to do this in my scenario... I hope you will help.
I want to output the data from stdout and/or stderr from a Popen call in real time, to a socket connection, not to stdout. So sys.stdout.flush() don't work for me.

```py
data=sok.recv(512) #the command to execute
p = subprocess.Popen(data, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

#this work.. but not how i spected, if the subprocess ends too fast, i only get the first line
while p.poll() is None:
    sok.send(p.stdout.readline())

#this only send the last line
for i in p.stdout.readline():
    sok.send(i)
    sys.stdout.flush() #why sys.stdout? i don't use it
    p.stdout.flush()   #same result
```

Comment: You're calling `Popen` with `shell=True` on data you get from a network connection? You do know that you're creating a shell server this way, don't you?

Comment: Yes I know, but that's not the point. In fact, that is what I am trying to do, for fun.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

p.poll() indicates whether the process is executing. So it returns false as soon as the program exits. So that's not what you should be checking.

your code:

```
for i in p.stdout.readline():
```

reads a single line and then iterates over each letter in that line. Not what you wanted. Use:

```
for i in p.stdout.readlines():
```

which will return each line.

But that will read the entire file before producing any lines, probably not what you wanted.

So use:

```
for line in p.stdout:
```

Which should give you each line, line by line, until there is nothing more to read